# Do we have any security risk for exposing page Item GUID?

Tags: security, rss

We have number of article pages in our site. I am trying to create article RSS feed specifically for Facebook Instant Articles consumption.
As per their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/publishing/setup-rss-feed), each item in feed should have number of elements, among them, there is one <*guid*> element (*A string that provides a unique identifier for this article in your feed.*), Is it ok to pass Article Page Item Id for <*guid*> element? or do i need to send a randomly generated guid?

What are the security risks, if we expose Sitecore Item Guids?

I had already asked the same question in sitecore-chat slack channel, but the question was lost with other conversations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no security issue with exposing Item GUID, but It depend on the client also if client doesn't want to expose the item ID of there solution. Then you need to think about any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no risk.

Sitecore clean installation items are well know to every Sitecore develop (or at least easily accessible ;) ), like `/sitecore` node guid is `{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}`.

Assuming that your solution is safe, you can expose all your item guids without any risk.

Comment: Thank you, even i was thinking like everyone already aware of the Item ID's present in some of the Sitecore packages we install (media framework, wffm).